Errors with trying to install electron
Trying to install electron in Windows Terminal as administrator with the command npm install electron and here are the errors from the terminal:
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\name> npm install electron

npm warn deprecated boolean@3.2.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.

npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [

npm warn cleanup   [

npm warn cleanup     'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\name\\node_modules\\@szmarczak',

npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\xampp\htdocs\name\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist'] {

npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,

npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',

npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',

npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\name\\node_modules\\@szmarczak\\http-timer\\dist'

npm warn cleanup     }

npm warn cleanup   ],

npm warn cleanup   [

npm warn cleanup     'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\name\\node_modules',

npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\xampp\htdocs\name\node_modules\got\dist\source'] {

npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,

npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',

npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',

npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\name\\node_modules\\got\\dist\\source'

npm warn cleanup     }

npm warn cleanup   ]

npm warn cleanup ]

npm error code 1

npm error path C:\xampp\htdocs\name\node_modules\electron

npm error command failed

npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js

npm error Error: Generated checksum for "electron-v33.2.0-win32-x64.zip" did not match expected checksum.

npm error     at Hash.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\name\node_modules\sumchecker\index.js:133:20)

npm error     at Hash.emit (node:events:519:28)

npm error     at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:832:12)

npm error     at onEofChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:810:5)

npm error     at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:464:5)

npm error     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)

npm error     at node:internal/streams/transform:141:12

npm error     at Hash._flush (node:internal/crypto/hash:104:3)

npm error     at Hash.final [as _final] (node:internal/streams/transform:128:10)

npm error     at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:914:14)

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\sum1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-14T01_52_50_541Z-debug-0.log

What's the problem?
I don't even know where to start. I didn't actually try anything to solve this.

Faced same issue today.
Seems it was already a problem once but it wasn't fixed: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/44582
now it's raised here again:
https://github.com/electron/get/issues/304
